# Translate quantifiers into senstance

Tags: logic, translation

How can I translate the following into reasonable sentence ?

[image]

You can let Rxyz stand for anything as long as it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a mathematical example, see the "standard" [epsilon-delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit) definition of limit :

> **for all** epsilon, **exists** a delta such that, **for all** x ...

For a natural language example, see Jan von Plato, [Elements of Logical Reasoning](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/110761077X) (2013), page 118 :

> A sequence of quantifiers such as ∀x∃y∀z is quite natural.
>
> > *There is for every person some problem on which every attempt will fail*.
>
> The three-place relation here is: person **x** fails on problem **y** in attempt **z**. This example also illustrates the choice of a domain. In this case the domain seems to contain, at least, persons, problems, and attempts. There is a threeplace relation that we can write as **Fail(x, y, z)**, in which **x** is a person, **y** a problem, and **z** an attempt. These have to go in the right places in the relation.
>
> The usual way to do it is to introduce predicates such as **Person(x), Problem(y)**, and **Attempt(z)**, and to write the formalization as in:
>
> > **∀x∃y∀z [Person(x) and Problem(y) and Attempt(z) → Fail(x, y, z) ]**.

---

Note that

> **∀x∃y∀zRxyz**

by *Double Negation* is equivalent to :

> **¬¬∀x∃y∀zRxyz**.

Now, using the rules for quantifiers :

- **¬∀** is equivalent to **∃¬**

and :

- **¬∃** is equivalent to **∀¬**

we can "move inside" the inner negation, getting :

> > **¬∃x∀y∃z¬Rxyz**.

Thus, the two formulae are equivalent.

---

Thus, the equivalent version of :

> *There is for every person some problem on which every attempt will fail*

can be read as :

> *There is no person such that for every problem there is an attempt which does not fail*.

Comment: I think you translated the first part correctly `(∀x∃y∀zRxyz) = "There is for every person some problem on which every attempt will fail."` but now how would you translate `¬∃x∀y∃z¬Rxyz` ? By the way that's all I was asking for. (+1 for the extra stuff)